# How to list all kubernetes objects with specific label using client-go

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl, client-go

I want to execute equivalent of

`kubectl get all -l app=myapp -n mynamespace`

or

`kubectl label all -l version=1.2.0,app=myapp track=stable --overwrite`

using client-go

I looked at [dynamic](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/dynamic) package, but it seems like it needs `GroupVersionResource`, which is different for, say, Service objects and Deployment objects. Also when I pass `schema.GroupVersionResource{Group: "apps", Version: "v1"}` it doesn't find anything, when I pass `schema.GroupVersionResource{Version: "v1"}` it finds only namespace object and also doesn't looks for labels, though I provided label options:

```
resource := schema.GroupVersionResource{Version: "v1"}
listOptions := metav1.ListOptions{LabelSelector: fmt.Sprintf("app=%s", AppName), FieldSelector: ""}
res, listErr := dynamicClient.Resource(resource).Namespace("myapps").List(listOptions)
```

I also looked at runtime package, but didn't find anything useful. I took a look at how `kubectl` implement this, bit haven't figured it out yet, too many levels of abstractions.

Answer (score 10):

You can't list "all objects" with one call.

Unfortunately the way Kubernetes API is architected is via API groups, which have multiple APIs under them.

So you need to:

1. Query all API groups (`apiGroup`)
2. Visit each API group to see what APIs (`kind`) it exposes.
3. Actually query that `kind` to get all the objects (here you may actually filter the list query with the label).

Fortunately, `kubectl api-versions` and `kubectl api-resources` commands do these.

So to learn how kubectl finds all "kinds" of API resources, run:

```
kubectl api-resources -v=6
```

and you'll see kubectl making calls like:

- `GET https://IP/api`
- `GET https://IP/apis`
- then it visits every api group:

  - `GET https://IP/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1`
  - `GET https://IP/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1`
  - ...

So if you're trying to clone this behavior with client-go, you should use the same API calls, <strike>or better just write a script just shells out to `kubectl api-resources -o=json` and script around it.</strike>

If you aren't required to use client-go, there's a [kubectl plugin called `get-all`](https://github.com/corneliusweig/ketall) which exists to do this task.

Comment: `kubectl api-resources -o=json` gives me `error: --output json is not available`.

Comment: Ah, yeah turns out it's not there. I might've assumed its existence. Today, there's a `kubectl get-all` plugin available.

Answer (score 0):

You can list all objects with:

```
kubectl get all
```

To list objects matching a specific label use:

```
kubectl get all --selector key=value
```

where "key" is the name of the label and "value" is the value you're trying to match.

To list all the objects in a namespace use:

```
kubectl get all --namespace "NAMESPACE"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```golang
objectsToList := []schema.GroupVersionKind{
  schema.GroupVersionKind{
    Group:   "apps",
    Kind:    "DeploymentList",
    Version: "v1",
  },
}

for _, o := range objectsToList {
  // Using an unstructured object.
  u := &unstructured.UnstructuredList{}
  u.SetGroupVersionKind(schema.GroupVersionKind{
    Group:   o.Group,
    Kind:    o.Kind,
    Version: o.Version,
  })
  err := c.List(context.Background(), u)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("cannot List Objects")
  }
}
```